# Why is the password displaying instead of the message?

Tags: c++, encryption, binary, codeblocks

I have a homework problem. https://gyazo.com/443dd9aee7b2ebe24a3a781d97150a70 . At the end, I try to decrypt the ciphertext but it is just showing the password, instead of the message! Please help! This is due very soon!

I have tried switching up the xor gate equation but it didn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string m;
    cout << "Please enter your message" << endl;
    getline(cin, m);

    cout << " " << endl;

    char p;
    cout << "Please enter a one-character password" << endl;
    cin >> p;

    cout << " " << endl;

    cout << "Encrypting..." << endl;

    cout << " " << endl;
    string c;

    for (int i = 0; i<m.length(); i++) {
        c += m[i]^p;
    }

    cout << "Your ciphertext is " << endl;
    cout << c << endl;

    cout << " " << endl;

    cout << "Decrypting..." << endl;

    string m2;
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++) {
        m2 = c[i+1]^p;
    }

    cout << "Your message is" << endl;
    cout << m2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In the end, I really need the m2 to display as the message, not the password.

Comment: Did you mean `m2 += c[i+1]^p;`?

Comment: ...Or better still, `m2 += c[i]^p;`?

Comment: You are a god!! How can i select a comment as best answer?

Comment: [Debugging, debugging, debugging...](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) That's almost always how to figure out these kind of things.

Comment: No need, my work here is done. [leaps out window, flies away into sunset]

Answer (score 0):

Beta answered the question.

I had the change the equation to m2 += c[i]^p;